# Form CSS styles are impacting bootstrap buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a form template called sky-forms. There are several CSS styles that are applied across the form from this template that make my bootstrap buttons look very strange (button text with colour background). Is there a way for my bootstrap buttons to somehow ignore the sky-forms styles?

The styles that seem to be causing the issues with bootstrap are the following:

```
.sky-form *,
.sky-form *:after,
.sky-form *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

When I remove those styles my bootstrap submit buttons look fine, but the form breaks.

Comment: Helping you will be easier if you can replicate the problem with the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People often add `!important` after rules to override other styles, such as

```
.myclass {
    color: red! important;
}
```

However, i dislike that method.

So regarding your issue, it looks like the theme is a bit shoddy. `.sky-form *` means "any element inside `.sky-form`". So it's making everything (`button`,`input`,`div`,`p`) inside `.sky-form` as `box-sizing: content-box;`. Taking a look at [Bootstrap's buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons), they seem to have their `box-sizing` is `box-sizing: border-box;`. So what I would do is override the buttons again (in my own style.css file) and replcae the `box-sizing` properties with `border-box`.

So ...

```
.sky-form .btn,
.sky-form .btn:after,
.sky-form .btn:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

that should fix your issue. You might want to add in default padding as well (`padding: 6px 12px;`).

Comment: Using your posted code and adding the padding seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: If you're having other issues with other elements, but head into Bootstraps code and look for it's default value and overwrite it again.

Answer (score 0):

The `.sky-form { box-sizing: content-box }` resets the `* { box-sizing: border-box }` that's used in Bootstrap. The `border-box` value makes the width of an element include content, padding and border instead of just the content.

Perhaps it's enough to simply override the `box-sizing` again for the Bootstrap elements used inside the `.sky-form`. To do so for a button `.btn` add the following to your css:

```
.btn,
.btn:before,
.btn:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I've tried to add a small example on how this might work, the `.sky-form` class has been copied from your code, so doesn't include all sky-form's styling

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.sky-form *,
.sky-form *:after,
.sky-form *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}

.btn,
.btn:before,
.btn:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Default Bootstrap button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="sky-form">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Bootstrap button inside a sky-form</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [Third party support - Box-sizing](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-box-sizing) inside Bootstrap's documentation for more information. This is about Bootstrap's `box-sizing` breaking third party components, but might give you a better explanation.

**P.S.** This might not be enough as I think it is quite likely that there are more css declarations inside `.sky-form` that override Bootstrap's styling.

Comment: You're right. The two current answers both don't fix the issue. I'm having trouble narrowing down why this isn't working. I'm even struggling to recreate the issue in JSfiddle. As I mentioned, when I remove the CSS code in my original question, the button looks perfect, but the form breaks.

Comment: Ah I see! The `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` make every element inside the `.sky-form` have no margin and padding at all (due to the `*` part of the selector). If they are used as a css reset you could try setting then to `inherit` as Bootstrap already includes a css reset. Otherwise I'm afraid you'll have to use e.g. Chrome's DevTools and see which elements use these styles by inheriting them, and then adding them to those elements.